# Swift - using enum in switch statement

Tags: enums, swift, switch-statement

I get this error:

```
'NSNumber' is not a subtype of Cat
```

Here is the code:

```
enum Cat:Int {
    case Siamese = 0
    case Tabby
    case Fluffy
}

let cat = indexPath.row as Cat
    switch cat {
    case .Siamese:
        //do something
        break;
    case .Tabby:
        //do something else
        break;
    case .Fluffy:

        break;
    }
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The simple answer is, don't try to lie about the type; indexPath.row is an Int, not a Cat. However, don't let that stop you; what you're doing is extremely Swifty and you should keep going down this road. Very nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Cat.fromRaw(indexPath.row)` to get the enumeration.

Because the return value of `fromRaw()` is an *optional*, use it like thus:

```
if let cat = Cat.fromRaw (indexPath.row) {
  switch cat {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I handled this same kind of situation in a recent app was to use a Struct consisting entirely of static members, instead of an Enum - in part because I had more information to associate with each option, in part because I got sick of having to call `toRaw()` and `fromRaw()` everyplace, and in part because (as your example shows you've discovered) an Enum loses its advantage when it turns out that you can't cycle through, or get a complete list of, the cases.

So, what I did was this:

```
struct Sizes {
    static let Easy = "Easy"
    static let Normal = "Normal"
    static let Hard = "Hard"
    static func sizes () -> [String] {
        return [Easy, Normal, Hard]
    }
    static func boardSize (s:String) -> (Int,Int) {
        let d = [
            Easy:(12,7),
            Normal:(14,8),
            Hard:(16,9)
        ]
        return d[s]!
    }
}

struct Styles {
    static let Animals = "Animals"
    static let Snacks = "Snacks"
    static func styles () -> [String] {
        return [Animals, Snacks]
    }
    static func pieces (s:String) -> (Int,Int) {
        let d = [
            Animals:(11,110),
            Snacks:(21,210)
        ]
        return d[s]!
    }
}
```

Now when we get to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I can talk like this:

```
    let section = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row
    switch section {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = Sizes.sizes()[row]
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = Styles.styles()[row]
    default:
        cell.textLabel.text = "" // throwaway
    }
```

Essentially I've just used the two Structs as namespaces with some added intelligence. I'm not saying this is better than what you're doing; they are both eminently Swifty. It's just another idea to consider.

Comment: Cool. GoZoner technically answered the question. But I think I'll do some refactoring like this so I don't have to keep typing out strings. +1

Comment: You might want to consider at least an enum of strings instead of an enum of ints, along with a static function that returns a list of the cases, similar to what I'm doing.

Comment: How would you do something like `let style = Styles.Animals?` I get "NSString is not a subtype of Styles"

Comment: You lost me. Ask a whole separate question, perhaps? That way you can show your code...